# When printing out data from a POST request, request.POST.get() returns None in Django App

Tags: python, django, post, httprequest

I am building an ecommerce web app. I am trying to build the "add to cart" functionality using some stock html product card code and adding an event listener to the "add to cart" button. I initially tried to use a click event from the button, but I was unable to pull the product quantity and product name from the HTML product page. I then tried to use a form tag around the button, and then post the product name and product quantity using the post method. When the request reaches my server, I was trying to access the data (initially by simply printing it out so I can decide how to post it to my database) but when I try the request.POST.get('Product Name') or request.POST.get('Product Quantity') the value returned is "None". When I print request.body, the printed result is b'{'Product Name': , 'Product Quantity': . I can't seem to find a way to access this data for further use. Code Follows:

```
{% block scripts %}
<script src="/static/js/addToCart.js" defer></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Get Smart Products</h1>
<div class="container">
    <ul>
    {% for product in product_list %}
        <div class="container">
            <img src="/media/{{product.product_image}}">
            <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
            <li>{{ product.category }}</li>
            <li>{{ product.price }}</li>
            <li>{{ product.description }}</li>
            
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ product.name }}" id="prod_name">
            <label for="Quantity">Quantity</label>
            <div class="input-group text-center mb-3" style="width:130px;">
                <button class="input-group-text decrement-btn">-</button>
                <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control qty-input text-center" value="1" id="quantity-btn">
                <button class="input-group-text increment-btn">+</button>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}<button class="btn btn-danger addToCartBtn" id="addToCartBtn">Add to cart</button>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

JS code

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"

document.getElementById("addToCartBtn").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const product_input = document.getElementById("prod_name").value
    const product_quantity = Number(document.getElementById("quantity-btn").value)
    console.log(product_input,product_quantity)
    axios.post('/ecomm/addToCart/', {'Product Name': product_input, 'Product Quantity':product_quantity}).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
    })
})
```

django app.views code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import json
from .models import Product


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})

def fin_ed_tech(request):
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'get_smart.html', {'product_list': product_list})

def person_pod(request):
    return render(request, 'person_pod_essentials.html', {})

def exoskel_maint(request):
    return render(request, 'exoskeletonal_maintenance.html', {})

def outer_mind_clothing(request):
    return render(request, 'clothing_for_the_outer_mind_wall.html', {})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})

def search(request):
    return render(request, 'search.html', {})

def search_products(request):

    # print(request.GET.get('query'))
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    
    if Product.objects.filter(name__contains=query):
        db_vars = Product.objects.filter(name__contains=query)
        print(db_vars)
        db_data = list(db_vars.values())
        return JsonResponse({'db_data': db_data})
    else:    
        auth = OAuth1("793746cd4fcf40bda3e1bc6b5b31b277", "e99e19abfa7347cabbf2591bbf8f48e1")
        endpoint = f"http://api.thenounproject.com/icon/{query}"

        API_response = requests.get(endpoint, auth=auth)
        print(API_response.content)
        JSON_API_response = json.loads(API_response.content)
        image_url = JSON_API_response['icon']['preview_url']

        return JsonResponse({'url':image_url})
        # return render(request, 'search_results.html', {})

def addToCart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        prod_name = request.POST.get('Product Name')
        print(prod_name)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('get_smart/')

def Cart(request):
    pass
```

error I am getting

```
None
[05/Jul/2022 21:21:09] "POST /ecomm/addToCart/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Not Found: /ecomm/addToCart/get_smart/
[05/Jul/2022 21:21:09] "GET /ecomm/addToCart/get_smart/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4124
```

I am a beginner when it comes to all the languages and tech used here so I appreciate all suggestions with what to do. Thank you!

Comment: It is `Product Name`, not `Product Quantity`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what part of the code are you referring to?

Comment: Use `return HttpResponseRedirect('/get_smart/')` iso `return HttpResponseRedirect('get_smart/')`...

Answer (score 0):

Your fields are outside the form that you submitted. You have to write them inside like this:

```
{% block scripts %}
<script src="/static/js/addToCart.js" defer></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Get Smart Products</h1>
<div class="container">
   <ul>
      {% for product in product_list %}
      <div class="container">
         <img src="/media/{{product.product_image}}">
         <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
         <li>{{ product.category }}</li>
         <li>{{ product.price }}</li>
         <li>{{ product.description }}</li>
         <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ product.name }}" id="prod_name" name="Product Quantity">
            <label for="Quantity">Quantity</label>
            <div class="input-group text-center mb-3" style="width:130px;">
               <button class="input-group-text decrement-btn">-</button>
               <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control qty-input text-center" value="1" id="quantity-btn">
               <button class="input-group-text increment-btn">+</button>
            </div>
            {% csrf_token %}<button class="btn btn-danger addToCartBtn" id="addToCartBtn">Add to cart</button>
         </form>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
   </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Also, I suggest posting a product's id is better than its name.

Comment: I made that correction and I am still getting "None" returned for prod_name = request.POST.get('Product Name'). When I go to print prod_name = request.body, I get b'{"Product Name":"Algorithmic Equity Trading Using Python","Product Quantity":1}'. So I can see the inputs that I want, but they don't seem to be in the POST method.

Comment: `prod_name = request.POST.get('Product Name', False)` will give you False now, but then do `print(prod_name)` and I guess the print gives you what you want.